# on the quadratic form $5x^2-y^2$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$:

$A=\{\frac{5p^2-y^2}{4}\, | \, p, y \,\,\text{odd positive integers}, p\,\, \text{prime}\}$ and

$B=\{\frac{5x^2-y^2}{4}\, | \, x, y \,\,\text{odd positive integers}\}$.

Are there elements in $B$ which are not in $A$?

Comment: there's a problem with $1$ because it is not prime. Hence $1\in B$ but I think $1\notin A$. Apart from that very good question.

Comment: But you haven't prove that $1\notin A$, have you? @Dog_69

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm pretty sure but I don't have any proof.

Comment: Taking $p=5$ and $y=11$ shows that $1\in A$.

Comment: What is a minumum number in B that you can't prove it is in A?

Comment: For all odd $x$ and $y$ we have
$$5x^2-y^2=5(9x+4y)^2-(20x+9y)^2,$$
wherer $9x+4y$ and $20x+9y$ are again odd. This yields an infinite sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ to check for primes, where $x_0:=x$ and $y_0:=y$, and  $x_n$ and $y_n$ are defined recursively by
$$x_{n+1}=9x_n+4y_n\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y_{n+1}=20x_n+9y_n.$$

Comment: My guess: 45 and 81 are in A and not in B.

Comment: @xarles You mean, are in $B$ and not in $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{5\cdot9^2-3^2}{4}=99$, and if $\frac{5p^2-y^2}{4}=99$ for some prime number $p$, then
$$5p^2-y^2=396\equiv0\pmod{3},$$
from which it follows that $p\equiv y\equiv0\pmod{3}$. Because $p$ is prime it follows that $p=3$, and hence
$$y^2=5p^2-396=-351,$$
a contradiction. So $99\in B$ but $99\notin A$.